# Docker multistage build - why build in docker?

Tags: java, docker, maven

Docker/java newbie here. 
In [this doc](https://docs.docker.com/develop/dev-best-practices/) I see:

> Use multistage builds. For instance, you can use the `maven` image to
>   build your Java application, then reset to the `tomcat` image and copy
>   the Java artifacts...

I understand that we use containerization to ensure the runtime environment of the application is exactly as needed, but why do we need to run build in container too? Wouldn't it be enough to have an CI/CD pipeline which

- cleans build cache if/when/where needed
- just runs build again
- creates docker image using new artifacts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your build artifacts are portable and you don't consider the host build environment onerous, there's absolutely nothing wrong with doing it the way you describe.  If you look at Java Docker questions around SO, almost all of them have Dockerfiles like

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre
COPY myapp.jar /
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/myapp.jar"]
```

There's really two cases where I'd say you should prefer a multi-stage build over other alternatives:

1. You're working in a compiled language that produces non-portable binaries (C++, Go, Rust) and aren't working on a native-Linux host; if you build the application inside Docker it will be the same OS as the eventual Docker runtime.
2. Your application needs extensions, typically written in C, that require a full toolchain to build, but not to run; for example a Python MySQL interface.

If your build system is fairly standardized and produces a portable artifact, building the application on the host and copying it into an image is just fine.  Java jar files fit this pattern well; so do Javascript browser applications built via Webpack.

Answer (score 3):

"Everything as code" is a philosophy that recommends that we have everything checked into git so that if there is a disaster (say a pandemic that wipes out your workforce...), you can one day rebuild everything from your git repo and some binary repositories that hold the libraries you used. By 'everything', I mean the source-code, the build-system, all pipelines and all infrastructure.

It is not enough to maintain your source-code in a git repo because if it's not clear how it should be built then it has little value. For example, a 250kloc (thousand lines of code) java system may look like it'll compile with java-8, but there may be some logic that only works right under java-6. You assume it's java-8, because 250kloc is way too much code to read and understand, so you build and run it and it blows up in production because you used the wrong compiler or a different Linux distro. If your whole build environment is also in code and can be easily reproduced then this won't happen. You can just run `docker image build --tag mycompany/myimage .` (or even better, use a Makefile and just run `make`), then your app will rebuild itself using the tools the original developers intended.

Of course, we don't need to resort to a pandemic for this to be a useful technique. Trying to build open-source projects without detailed instructions is a PitA (Pain in the Ass), and even with instructions, it can take forever to find the right libraries and tools, to download them all, and to make them work together. This problem is exacerbated if you don't know the toolset very well (or at all). Put the build instructions in a docker container and boom -- you have a buildable project that's almost trivial to build with a testable and executable set of instructions.

This pattern is so powerful that these days I build everything in docker and include a `Makefile` to ensure that even the docker command is run as I intended. It's so much easier to type `make build` than the relevant `docker` commands. And, the whole thing is committed to git along with the source for my projects so that the build system is versioned along with the rest of the project.

The reason we use multi-stage builds is that that's easier than having multiple docker files, though it's basically the same thing but with fewer overheads and less chance of mistakes. Multi-stage builds exist so that you can include compilers and similar tools in the build stage and discard them in the final image. The intent is to keep the final image as small as possible. This helps reduce storage costs and speeds up the transmission of the image across the network, but perhaps more importantly for most people, this also reduces the attack-surface of the image. Fewer components mean fewer vulnerabilities. Why have a compiler in your production image if you're never going to compile anything in production? The compiler may have vulnerabilities. You may be patching vulnerabilities, but do you really want to patch and release to production a new service because of a compiler you never actually use in production? Of course not. So, mutli-stage builds help us by creating multiple images, stages, with different tools and configurations, but only the final one is tagged and released; the rest are discarded.

One of the many benefits of this approach is that we only have to specify our build procedure once and it will work anywhere. When integrating with continuous integration (CI) tools this saves us having to learn how to build our app in that specific tool and it saves us from errors that could be introduced if the CI tool is building things using a different approach to the way developers build things. If you use a containerised build you will be guaranteed that the devs and the CI platform are doing the same thing in the same ways using the same tools, which helps avoid the 'it works on my machine' class of errors. It also speeds up the development of your pipelines, because you only have to configure the pipeline to run the docker build (or, 'make', as mentioned earlier). This method ensures 'repeatability' of your build (or, rather, it should ensure this if it is done right - it's still quite easy to get it wrong).

I would highly recommend that you move to this approach as soon as possible. It is the mandated approach in all the large corporations I've worked in recently (mostly big European banks). Once you get used to doing this, previous approaches seem parochial at best and simply wrong at worst. This approach will save you a lot of time and effort and leads to higher-quality systems that are much easier to maintain, especially in these troubled times.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Could you please add: why this approach is better *when you have [properly configured] CI/CD pipeline*? We assume that the pipeline configuration is in the repo as well (e.g. Gitlab-CI).

Comment: Happy to help. Done.